# Application crash on startup when loading Mapview (java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: EnsureLocalCapacity)

Tags: android, google-maps, memory-leaks, android-mapview, mapfragment

Launching application after installation causes a crash only on Samsung phones. It does not occur on other phones. The error is

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: EnsureLocalCapacity:

The crash only occurs when launching the application for the first time after installation. When relaunching the app, it runs but it causes memory to keep adding on and never clear.

Here is the code:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_place_search_results, container, false)
    mapView = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.placesearchresults_map) as SupportMapFragment
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    mapView.getMapAsync(this)
    retainInstance = true
    return view
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    mapView.onResume()
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    mapView.onPause()
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    mapView.onStart()
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    map?.clear()
    mapView.onDestroy()
    mapMarkerFactor.recycle()
}

override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
}

override fun onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory()
    mapView.onLowMemory()
}
```

XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/placessearchresults_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

            <fragment
                class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                android:id="@+id/placessearchresults_map"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:clickable="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/placessearchresults_recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"/>

    <io.supercharge.shimmerlayout.ShimmerLayout
        android:id="@+id/placessearchresults_loading"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:shimmer_animation_duration="750"
        app:shimmer_auto_start="true"
        app:shimmer_color="@color/placeHolderShimmer"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                layout="@layout/placeholder_item_place_mini"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <include
                layout="@layout/placeholder_item_place_mini"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <include
                layout="@layout/placeholder_item_place_mini"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </io.supercharge.shimmerlayout.ShimmerLayout>



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is the Logcat

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: EnsureLocalCapacity
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.list0(Native Method)
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.list(UnixFileSystem.java:303)
    at java.io.File.list(File.java:1122)
    at java.io.File.listFiles(File.java:1286)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.ck.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280048@13.2.80 (040400-211705629):82)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.api.h.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280048@13.2.80 (040400-211705629):18)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.api.u.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280048@13.2.80 (040400-211705629):80)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.db.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280048@13.2.80 (040400-211705629):33)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bc.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280048@13.2.80 (040400-211705629):170)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bc.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280048@13.2.80 (040400-211705629):124)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.co.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280048@13.2.80 (040400-211705629):26)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.t.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280048@13.2.80 (040400-211705629):69)
    at fh.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280048@13.2.80 (040400-211705629):10)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:612)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zza.transactAndReadException(Unknown Source:7)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzj.onCreateView(Unknown Source:14)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source:18)
    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zzd.zza(Unknown Source:19)
    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.zza(Unknown Source:6)
    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.onCreateView(Unknown Source:20)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source:2)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2346)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.ensureInflatedFragmentView(FragmentManager.java:1664)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1399)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1659)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1905)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3715)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:186)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:772)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at com.myapplication.modules.place.search.results.PlaceSearchResultsFragment.onCreateView(SearchFragment.kt:88)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2346)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1428)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1759)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1827)
2018-10-05 10:12:46.272 22520-22520/com.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2596)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2383)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2338)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2245)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:703)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6940)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Thanks in advance